# How to add validation to multiple text fields in JOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing, validation, joptionpane

I have the following method which pops up a window when a button is clicked.

```
public void cardPopUp() {
    String[] cardTypes = {"Visa", "Mastercard", "Electron", "Cashcard"};

    JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(cardTypes);
    JTextField field1 = new JTextField("");
    JTextField field2 = new JTextField("");
    JTextField field3 = new JTextField("");
    JTextField field4 = new JTextField("");
    JTextField field5 = new JTextField("");

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
    panel.add(new JLabel("Card Type:"));
    panel.add(combo);
    panel.add(new JLabel("Cardholder Name:"));
    panel.add(field1);
    panel.add(new JLabel("Card Number:"));
    panel.add(field2);
    panel.add(new JLabel("Month Expiry:"));
    panel.add(field3);
    panel.add(new JLabel("Year Expiry:"));
    panel.add(field4);
    panel.add(new JLabel("CVC:"));
    panel.add(field5);

    int input = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(MainActivity.this, panel, "Card Payment",
            JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        if (input == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            Basket.orderNo+=1;
            dispose();
            new OrderConfirmationScreen().setVisible(true);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Payment Cancelled");
        }
}
```

How can i add validation so that the fields are checked to see if correct data was entered for a card payment. For example, `field1` should only allow text, `field2` should only allow a 16 digit number and so on.

I'm guessing i would need to create more methods that validate each field and then just call the method in `cardPopUp()` method.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [Validating Input](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example :

> `field1` should only allow text

```
if(field1.getText().matches("\\w+\\.?")){
  ...
}else{...}
```

> `field2` should only allow a 16 digit number

```
if(field2.getText().matches("(\\d{16})")){
  ...
}else{...}
```

And so on.

Comment: Im having trouble with the the `field2` example you gave. I have an error on the `.matches` Eclipse asks me to add cast to `field2` first then when i do it says 'cannot cast from JTextField to String'. I tried parsing `field2` but then it says 'cant invoke matches on the primitive type int'.

Comment: sorry you should to getText you have to use `field2.getText().matches("(\\d{16})")` i already edit my answer @user982467

Comment: `"^[\\p{L} .'-]+$"` this regex would be better suited for `field1` as it is the cardholder name and should allow spaces as well as some other special characters that people have in their names.

Answer (score 0):

as i understand your question what u want is to match the character types that are inputted, for this i would suggest to take a look at the String.matches see [javaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) using this you can setup a function that checks the input for any regrex epression and returns true or false, if this is NOT what you wanted i'm afraid i don't understand the question

Comment: just a recommendation for the future, if you don't know what the original poster want's don't answer it until you have a clear idea.